# Sublime Text custom autocomplete

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to add my own autocompelte words to sublime text but it seems like it is not working.

I took some help from
http://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/completions.html

and wrote my auto-complete code as:

```
{
    "scope": "source.cpp",
    "completions":
    [
    { "trigger": "cout", "contents": "std::cout << $1" },
    { "trigger": "endl", "contents": "<< std::endl $1" },
    { "trigger": "cin", "contents": "std::cin >> $1" }
    ]
}
```

where I want to replace `cout` with `std::cout` everytime.

Could anyone please tell me how to rectify this?

The file is called `cpp.sublime-completions` and is placed in

`/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall issue is that the top level scope for C++ files isn't `source.cpp`, it's `source.c++`. So as defined your completions don't work because Sublime doesn't realize that it should apply them.

You can check what the scope is at any given point by using `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` from the menu or pressing the associated keyboard shortcut, which is visible in the menu.

As an additional note, when you're using snippets/completions that only have a single placeholder variable in them as you're doing here, you may want to replace `$1` for `$0`.

Sublime moves through the completion fields in numerical order, requiring you to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to the next field, and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> when you're on the last field "exits" the snippet by jumping the cursor to the `$0` point (assumed to be the last thing in the snippet if you don't specify it explicitly).

As defined in your example, if you trigger for example `cout` the cursor will be position on the `$1` and you'll see `Field 1 of 2` in the status line to remind you that you're in a snippet. When you're done typing the placeholder you have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the snippet back to normal editing mode (various cursor manipulations also cancel out of snippet mode as well).

That might be what you want but it also leads to weirdly inexplicable issues if you're not expecting it (for example not being able to expand a snippet right away or the cursor jumping away to somewhere else when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the indexing for placeholders. I changed them to $0 and it works perfectly!